# IOSOpenDev Installation fails

Tags: xcode, macos, cydia

I Have Xcode 4.3.1 installed and I tried installing the 10.5 package for IOSOpenDev

This is the error I got
(I copied the entire log and I decided to put it in a pastebin)
http://pastebin.com/Qd3fSKgt

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the point:

> You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements,  please run
>   `'xcodebuild -license'` (for user-level acceptance)  or `'sudo xcodebuild
>   -license'` (for system-wide acceptance)  from within a Terminal window to review and agree to the Xcode license agreements.

This is a one-time thing you have to to, so I didn't remember about it before. I'm surprised anyway that this issue isn't stated anywhere in the website.